# Use Default Avatar in gravatar

Tags: gravatar

Is it possible to use a generic avatar if the user's email address is not in gravatar? I'd rather not use the colorful avatars, or the goofy ones that it auto generates.

Comment: Use a generic gravatar _where_? WordPress.com, for instance, offers a number of different options for undefined gravatars, including a basic silhouette. Implementing such a thing is dependent on the developer of the app.

Answer (score 1):

Gravatar doc specify 'd' parameter for that:

Code exemple in PHP from Gravatar doc:

```
$grav_url = "http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/" . md5( strtolower( trim( $email ) ) ) . "?d=" . urlencode( $default ) . "&s=" . $size;
```